# Can't draw negative $x$ values on HP 50G

Tags: calculator

I'm unable to find an option to change the range of the function I'm plotting on the [HP 50G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-49_series#HP_50g), can anyone tell me where it is? My graphs always start with $x>0$.

Comment: What is the function ?

Comment: Any given function, like x^2.